# Error 1316: while installing Mono for android on windows 7 (and visual studio 2010)

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, xamarin.android

I have been trying to install Mono For Android 4.2.7 on Windows 7 (With Visual Studio 2010)

It detects that only it needs to install Android SDK and Visual Studio Plug-in (Which is correct since I am currently using MonoDevelop and Android SDK to develop Apps before attempting to install)

When it gets to installing the Visual Studio Plug-in it shows an error. 
I have tried many times, restarting my computer, ensuring all related apps are closed, and still getting the same thing.

The Log says a Network issue. I understand that it stores the files (Locally temprorily) so what is got to do with Network :(

Part of the Log file is below, any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
[2012-11-08 05:55:23.450] [Info] Installation ID: 583be3ec-0405-4778-8fc8-5794c02dfe5f
[2012-11-08 05:55:23.450] [Info] Operating system: Windows 7 v6.1.7601.65536 (Enterprise (Service Pack 1); Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1), 64-bit
[2012-11-08 05:55:23.450] [Info] Installer version: 2.1.1.28292
[2012-11-08 05:55:23.451] [Info] Status: in progress


Some lines here about successfully installing Android SDK were removed. 


[2012-11-08 05:56:25.918] [Info] Skipping installation of software item 'MonoDevelop'
[2012-11-08 05:56:25.918] [Info] Installing software item 'Mono for Android, VisualStudio and MonoDevelop'
[2012-11-08 05:56:25.918] [Info] Installing an MSI
[2012-11-08 05:56:25.918] [Info] Database path: <USER_HOME>\Temp\MonoForAndroid\downloads\mono-android-4.2.7.15330979.msi
[2012-11-08 05:56:25.918] [Info] Starting MSI installation: msiexec /i "<USER_HOME>\Temp\MonoForAndroid\downloads\mono-android-4.2.7.15330979.msi" /quiet /passive /log "<USER_HOME>\Temp\tmpEBB8.tmp" ADDLOCAL=VisualStudioAddin
[2012-11-08 05:56:27.337] [Info] MSI installation process exited with code 1603
[2012-11-08 05:56:27.337] [Info] Status: failed.
[2012-11-08 05:56:27.337] [Info] InstallMsi failed for '<USER_HOME>\Temp\MonoForAndroid\downloads\mono-android-4.2.7.15330979.msi'
[2012-11-08 05:56:27.337] [Exception] Exception was thrown.
[2012-11-08 05:56:27.337] [Exception] System.InvalidOperationException: MSI execution failed.


[2012-11-08 05:56:27.337] [Exception] at WindowsInstaller.WindowsInstallationArchiveHandler.InstallMsi(String file, Boolean needsPrivileges)
[2012-11-08 05:56:27.337] [Info] BEGIN >>>>>> msiexec log: '<USER_HOME>\Temp\tmpEBB8.tmp'
[Info] === Logging started: 8/11/2012  16:56:26 ===
[Info] Action start 16:56:26: INSTALL.


[Info] Action ended 16:56:26: AppSearch. Return value 1.
[Info] MSI (s) (40:20) [16:56:27:103]: Product: Mono for Android 4.2.7 -- Error 1316. A network error occurred while attempting to read from the file: C:\Users\hasn.aitaiar\AppData\Local\Temp\MonoForAndroid\downloads\4776efd4-a061-4c4c-a6bf-50eb08119eb1-1348755828.msi
[Info] Error 1316. A network error occurred while attempting to read from the file: C:\Users\hasn.aitaiar\AppData\Local\Temp\MonoForAndroid\downloads\4776efd4-a061-4c4c-a6bf-50eb08119eb1-1348755828.msi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this just now.
Go to your Temp Folder, `\AppData\Local\Temp\MonoForAndroid\downloads\mono-android-4.2.7.15330979.msi`

Run it from there and click uninstall first.

Install again and the setup will be completed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this issue is resolved in MonoForAndorid in its latest version